# Make Video Sequence Editor (VSE) playback in real time?

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video, performance

How do I make the Video Sequence Editor (VSE) playback in real time?

I have some 4K video clips that I want to edit, however, I'm unable to do so because when I hit play I get about 2 FPS playback (even without any effects/Modifiers applied) instead of the video clips/timelines 25 FPS.

I have a pretty powerful computer, and these clips have no problem playing back in, for example, Premiere. I know Blender's VSE isn't the best or most powerful, but there's gotta be a way to playback the video and audio clips you edit in real time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import footage in the VSE for optimal playback and organization?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182692/how-to-import-footage-in-the-vse-for-optimal-playback-and-organization)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a very powerful computer you might want to try using a different app. Blender vse is a very outdated tool that doesn't really use all of the potential of your hardware. No gpu acceleration, limited multithreading. The only solution for blender is working with proxies at a lower res. If premiere works fine for you, keep using premiere. Blender is a wonderful 3D creation app, but the video editing tools have not advanced to the needs of today's users.

Comment: For those downvoting please leave some arguments. If blender is weak in some areas take your issues to the developers. Don't shoot the messenger.