# Video Sequencer Cache Button Exists?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, cache

Is there a button in the Video Sequencer that, when pressed, will cache as much of the timeline as possible?

Comment: Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182692/how-to-import-footage-in-the-vse-for-optimal-playback-and-organization

Answer (score 2):

In the preview sidebar, you'll find Prefetch Frames:

[image]