# Can VSE not generate proxies for scene strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I placed the scene proxy on the VSE timeline and clicked on Rebulid Proxy and Timecode Indices, but I didn’t get any cache.
Below are tests for some situations.

- Only image sequence on the timeline:
  The proxy gauge builds up as the proxy gauge slowly rises.
- Image sequence and scene strip on the timeline:
  Nothing happens after’Buliding Proxeis 0%’ flashes for 1 second.
- Only scene strip:
  Nothing happens after’Buliding Proxeis 0%’ flashes for 1 second.

**Q: Why can VSE create a cache for a scene strip through playback, but not Rebuild Proxy and TImecode Indices?**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182692/how-to-import-footage-in-the-vse-for-optimal-playback-and-organization

Comment: I reviewed the link. After all, it was about image footage and it didn't solve my curiosity about the scene strip.

Comment: Currently is only Movie strips which can have proxies, ifaik, however disk cache should support all formats, but will need to saved to SSD or else it'll be very slow.
Disk cache does not support Prefetch Frames(cache), so in order to cache all frames continuously, in Timeline change Playback to No Synth.