# Blender preview in video editor is really slow, barely using my computer's resources

Tags: video-sequence-editor, eevee-render-engine, video

I set the memory cache limit to 12gb, I'm running on ssd, I even set the resolution to 5% yet blender is ungodly slow. I'm only getting around 5 fps and blender starts to lag heavily when I start to add effect strips like speeding up the video or adding overlays. The playback is set to No sync.

I know I have a slow system but this is ridiculous. I'm running on a AMD Ryzen 2400g and a Radeon 570 with 16 gigs of ram but I noticed that its only using 13% of the CPU, 235mb of ram and it barely touched the GPU.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm editing a 3 min phone video, uncompressed 1080x1920, using the Eevee engine

Comment: Try this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXs21UilNYQ
Or this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182692/how-to-import-footage-in-the-vse-for-optimal-playback-and-organization

Comment: @tintwotin thank you for the suggestion but I'l just install DaVinci Resolve. Blender's sequence editor is just too frustrating to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have a very powerful computer, but blender is not making use of it's resources.

Blender video editor is quite outdated and does not take advantage of the hardware. Limited multithreading and hardly any use of the GPUs capabilities. Blender is wonderful for 3D content creation, but the Video Editing side of the program is not robust at all, and has not grown to the meet the needs of today's users.

Try using a dedicated video editing app, like resolve free. With a setup like yours it should run smooth and problem free. No need to use proxies or transcoding.

Comment: This kind of answers get down-voted all the time, but those votes should go towards the improvement of blenders VSE, not to those who point out the limitations on the program, and want to save users time and frustration...

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there are a couple of things you could test, if they will improve the performance.

Try the Prefetch Frames(Cache) in the Preview Sidebar:

[image]

Try the new Disk Cache, which may be fast enough if you point it to save on a SSD:

[image]

Another thing to test is to make the project resolution(default 1920x1089) match your footage resolution(1080x1920), by selecting the strip and select this:
[image]

Cache handling seems to have improved in 2.91: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Finally you can try to use proxies. This add-on makes the process very simple and fast:
https://github.com/cgvirus/blender-vse-easy-proxy

FYI: Work is being done in this area currently. Ex. yesterday a dev found a way to speed up ffmpeg with 24%:

[image]

Comment: Those tips helped a lot, thanks!