# Videos from my cell phone have slow playback in VSE preview

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, performance, cache

Usually when I drag a video from Zoom or my Cannon camera, the preview will play back at full speed. However, when I drag in a video from my cell phone, it only gets ~3 FPS. (Interestingly, the video plays at full speed in VLC.)

I have tried playing with the frame cache and proxy settings, and while it helps with a section of video that has already been played without av-sync, this does not answer the question of why my cell phone video decodes slowly.

Is there some type of preprocessing or transcoding that can be done with something like ffmpeg before importing it into Blender?

If you recommend transcoding, then what settings would you use to minimize recompression lossyness?

I am using Blender 2.83 under Linux.

Thank you for your help!!1

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195339/movie-recorded-on-phone-reports-inconsistent-number-of-frames-when-imported-to-b/195341#195341 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185150/image-overlay-out-of-sync-with-timeline-after-rendering/185155#185155 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190742/blender-preview-in-video-editor-is-really-slow-barely-using-my-computers-resou/190769#190769

Comment: Good information, but what codecs is blender most effective at rendering? Can I use ffmpeg to preprocess the video and avoid using "Prefetch Frames"?

Comment: For faster rendering out of Blender you can find some of the parallel rendering options listed here: https://blenderartists.org/t/video-sequence-editor-news-add-ons/1188770 The fastest output codec AVI JPEG or AVI RAW, but you'll have to Render Audio... and merge it afterwards.  
For rendering proxies faster - to avoid using Prefetch Frames - try this add on: https://github.com/cgvirus/blender-vse-easy-proxy